# Detect if selected shape / table is in edit mode with VBA?

Tags: vba, alignment, powerpoint, selection, shapes

I'm trying to write a PowerPoint VBA macro that would act differently whether a shape is merely selected or is in edit mode (i.e. the cursor to edit the text is present, see image).[image]

Is there a way to check this using VBA in PowerPoint? I haven't been able to find on this anything so far

My ultimate goal being:

- If just the shape is selected, the macro will align the shape left
- If the shape is in edit mode, the macro will align the text left (and leave the shape where it is)

Any help would be appreciated
Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using Selection.Type. If it returns 2, the shape is selected. If the insertion point is in the text, it will return 3:

```
Sub DetectShapeOrText()
    MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.Type
End Sub
```

[PpSelectionType enumeration (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppselectiontype)

Comment: Would you happen to know how to check for a table whether the shape table is selected or if several cells in the table are selected ? In both case Selection.Type return 2

In the first case I wish to do actions on the selected shape, and in the second case I want to do actions on the text in the selected cells